# How to trigger an event when node is saved?

Tags: 8, nodes

I am trying to execute a piece of code when a node is saved. I am using `hook_node_update`, but it's never triggered when updating a node. Here is my code:

```
function custom_node_update(Drupal Core Entity EntityInterface $node) {
 // Logs a notice
 \Drupal::logger('custom')->notice("entity was updated");
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to code had syntax error.

The correct code will be

```
function custom_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  // Logs a notice
  \Drupal::logger('custom')->notice("entity was updated");
}
```

Comment: Should just do a `use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface` at the top of the file. Then just refer to it as `EntityInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should look at using [hook_entity_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/8.3.x). Also, is that code in a module called "custom"? And is that module enabled? Last thing ... the parameter should look something like this `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity`.  You are missing slashes.